# How do I play the system sound from an osx application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, audio

I am trying to play the default system beep sound in my program.  I can play a specified sound, but I want to play the alert sound that is set in the Sound System Preferences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call [`NSBeep()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/1473622-nsbeep). It's a part of AppKit.

Comment: Wow that was easy.  Thanks!

Comment: In Swift `NSSound.beep()`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the accepted answer could be to use [AudioServicesPlayAlertSound](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/1405202-audioservicesplayalertsound), passing it the `kSystemSoundID_UserPreferredAlert` parameter.

However, this has the drawback to require the `AudioToolbox` Framework in the app.